# The HTTP verb POST used to access path '/' is not allowed on HTML page

Tags: c#, javascript, iis, lightbox

So I have a link on my aspx page that Im trying to trigger a separate html using lightbox. whenever I click the link the lightbox works fine but the html that is being loaded is giving me the error below. BUT if I use an aspx file instead of an html file it works BUT it shows the page twice! I've searched and I dont know if editing the aspnet_isapi.dll will really work. First of all I don't even know where to find it. Any thoughts? 
Thanks!

> The HTTP verb POST used to access path
>   '/test.html' is not allowed. 
>   Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the
>   current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.Web.HttpException: The HTTP
>   verb POST used to access path
>   '/PersonEditor_WebApp/test.html' is
>   not allowed.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated
>   during the execution of the current
>   web request. Information regarding the
>   origin and location of the exception
>   can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.

***************EDIT FOR CODE******************************

```
    <tr>
    <td><asp:Button ID="bLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" onclick="bLogin_Click" /></td>
    <td><asp:LinkButton ID="lbForgotPassword" runat="server" href="confirmcancel.html" autopostback="true" OnClick="lbForgotPassword_OnClick">Forgot Password</asp:LinkButton></td>
    <td><asp:Label ID="lbLoginError" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" 
            CssClass="validator"></asp:Label></td>

</tr>
```

***********this is the one on the cs file**************************

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = true;
    //register javascripts and setup buttons
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Prototype", "<script src='Scripts/prototype.js' language=javascript></script>");
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "LigthBoxScript", "<script src='Scripts/lightbox.js'></script>");
    lbForgotPassword.CssClass = "lbOn";


}
```

Comment: Do you remember to prevent the link action when you open the lightbox? If not you will load the lightbox and the link will make the browser go to whatever page the links points to.

Comment: what do you mean prevent the link action?

Comment: We need more info. Please post source code.

Comment: This is unrelated, but you misspelled `LigthBoxScript` when you register the script...

Comment: I dont think that will matter. Isn't that just a string to describe the registered file/script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I think i solved it. But not really.

I was able to make the lightbox load the correct page but it needs to be an aspx page. if i use a normal html page I get the error again...

And I used the same lines of codes btw. 
So i guess i just have to make do with an aspx page.
If anybody would know why a regular html page will give the error please feel free to post an answer.

Thanks much!
-G